Format one word in bold at a given bookmark
I'm trying to insert text at a given bookmark named "bmk_condition". The text consists of a condition number, a description, and a deadline (if available).
I want the condition and its number (e.g., Condition 2) to be in bold, while the rest should be in normal text.

From what I gathered on various forums, I need to set the bookmark.range.font.bold property. However, my "Condition .." text remains unformatted.
Here is a sample of my code (data extraction is omitted for brevity):
Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim wdBmk As Word.Bookmark
    
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add("template.dotx", False, 0)

wdApp.Visible = True
wdDoc.Activate

Set wdBmk = pWdDoc.Bookmarks("bmk_condition")
wdBmk.Range.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart

'Insert condition #2
wdBmk.Range.Font.Bold = False
wdBmk.Range.Text = "Lorem Ipusm" & vbCrLf & "Deadline: xxxxxx"
wdBmk.Range.Font.Bold = True
wdBmk.Range.Text = "Condition 2"

'Insert condition #1
wdBmk.Range.Font.Bold = False
wdBmk.Range.Text = "Lorem Ipsum"
wdBmk.Range.Font.Bold = True
wdBmk.Range.Text = "Condition 1"


Uploading images is generally discouraged. Is there any way you could [edit] your question to include that document as text instead of an image? I know it's a little weird because of the bookmark, but there has to be some kind of workaround...

Hello Andrew,
Thank you for your comment. The code is shown below the image. I included the image because I believe it illustrates the issue clearly—after all, a picture is worth a thousand words.

On this site specifically, pictures are not great. That link provides many reasons why you should avoid them whenever possible, including screen reader compatibility, loading time/data rates, and data dumps. Even if that picture conveys your message well, how much worse would your post be if you provided it as text instead?

I'm assuming here that the Bookmark is a 0-char length 'insertion point' (I think it is based on your picture of the document).
Your core problem is that when you do wdBmk.Range.Font.Bold = True (or False) then your code is acting on the 0-char length location of the Bookmark ... not on the text you have added. You can fix this as follows:
Add this Sub:
Sub AddTextToBookmark(doc As Word.Document, wdBmk As Word.Bookmark, sText As String, bBold As Boolean)
    Dim rng As Word.Range
    wdBmk.Range.Text = sText & vbCrLf
    Set rng = doc.Range(wdBmk.Start, wdBmk.Start + Len(sText))
    rng.Font.Bold = bBold
End Sub

'AddTextToBookmark()' does the core of the 'adding text' and 'making bold'. Now to use it, remove all of your existing code following the Set wdBmk = pWdDoc.Bookmarks("bmk_condition") line, then add:
AddTextToBookmark wdDoc, wdBmk, "Lorem Ipusm" & vbCrLf & "Deadline: xxxxxx", False
AddTextToBookmark wdDoc, wdBmk, "Condition 2", True
AddTextToBookmark wdDoc, wdBmk, "Lorem Ipsum" & vbCrLf, False
AddTextToBookmark wdDoc, wdBmk, "Condition 1", True

You also have, I think, a typo in the code you have posted in the question ... (pWdDoc instead of wdDoc) ... are you using "Option Explicit"?

Thank you very much John - you are right, there was a typo that was not caught up because I didn't add the "Option Explicit" on top of my sample module. I will correct it straight away.
Best wishes and once again, thank you very much, Laurent

Keep in mind that Bold (and Italics) is a toggle property. If the underlying text already has bold set, adding it to selected text will actually turn it off.
